# Form without submit button on Enter

Tags: html, forms, form-submit, submit-button

For form, without submit button, with 1 text input, do submit on Enter.

For form, without submit button, with more than 1 text input, do not submit on Enter.

Should both not submit on Enter?

```html
<!-- This one do submit on Enter --> 
<form action="/">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
</form>

<!-- This one do not submit on Enter --> 
<form action="/">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Jerry">
</form>
```

Comment: https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/01/01/enter-should-submit-forms-stop-messing-with-that/#no-submit-buttons

Comment: @racz_gabor Post it as answer! (for reference on HTML specs it's 4.10.22.2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the form has no submit button, then the implicit submission
>   mechanism must do nothing if the form has **more than one** field that
>   blocks implicit submission, and must submit the form element from the
>   form element itself otherwise.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#implicit-submission

You can see here how the forms works with no submit button:
https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/01/01/enter-should-submit-forms-stop-messing-with-that/#no-submit-buttons

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is not okay to suppress the Enter key as a way to submit a form. That being put away, you can achieve this kind of functionality, using the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library for JavaScript (it will be easier for you to use).

Here is a modified version of your HTML. I have added a data attribute to identify those forms, which would not submit on Enter key:

```
<!-- This one WILL NOT submit, when the Enter key is pressed -->
<form action="/" data-disable-enter="1">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
</form>

<!-- This one WILL submit, when the Enter key is pressed
     If you want to suppress the Enter key submission, add the data attribute data-disable-enter="1" -->
<form action="/">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Jerry">
</form>
```

And here is the JavaScript code, using the jQuery library to suppress the Enter key form submission. An event listener is attached to listen for the `keydown` event on each of the form elements (input, select and textarea) in all forms that have the data attribute `data-disable-enter="1"`. If the pressed key code is 13 ([which means "Enter"](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)), then we would prevent the default action, associated with the key pressing, which in our case is the form submission.

```
jQuery("form[data-disable-enter='1']").find("input, select, textarea").on("keydown", function(e){
    // 13 is the key code for the Enter key
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: AFAIK OP is asking why a form is submitted without a `submit` button/input, he was not trying to disable submission itself

Comment: Should I delete my answer?

Comment: That's only up to you! If it doesn't get any downvote you may leave it there in case someone will need it in future